# Creating sharepoint quality review system

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, quality-assurance

I've been tasked with creating the following flows in SharePoint but at am a loss of where to start.

$User1 creates a document and when the document is ready it is sent to approval by multiple (specific) users.
If the users have comments and don't approve the document, the document is sent back to $User1 with comments and we're back to square one.
If the users approve, it is then released, meaning it is sent to a specific email address.

Any and all tips / pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like out of the box content approval workflow.

If you want more customized version then start by creating a designer workflow.